# Importing a CSV to Mathematica

Tags: csv, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to import a csv file to mathematica to form a list of lists  I tried using this Import["file"] and this Import["file" -> ","] but the file is allawys read as a string and when I apply ToExpression[] the output is only the third column of the table from the file. What shall i do?

Comment: Look at SemanticImport.

Comment: If you could create a small example file that has the same behavior and you could put that file where someone could get it without needing to sign up, register, log in, etc. then people would be able to duplicate your result, diagnose why and show you a way to resolve the problem.

Comment: does the file name actually have a csv extension?

Comment: Ok so here's how it worked `SemanticImport["C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\EM20.csv", Automatic,
"Rows"]`